# Partial View not loading data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to load a partial view of inside a tab but its not showing data.

I am using the following code can I not just do a loop using razor code this is in a partial view which I wish to load in from another view

```
@model IEnumerable<solitude.models.ProductImages>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ProductPicturesList";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginAdminLte.cshtml";
}

<h2>ProductPicturesList</h2>



<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
               Picture Title
            </th>


            <th>
                Image
            </th>


    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
            </tr>


        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">Delete</a>
        </td>

        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Its cause in the main list I am using a view model but I want to show a list of pictures above the form upload what would my best way of doing this be as obv  it is not returning anyresults I am using a controller for my main page.

```
@model solitude.models.Models.ViewModels.ProductImageVm 
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@

@Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicturesList.cshtml")

<div class="form-group">

 <form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="FileUpload" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">



    <input asp-for="Title" />
    <input asp-for="ProductId" type="hidden" />
    <input asp-for="Image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Edit 2**
My Product Images as a class should this be changed

```
public   class ProductImages
{


        [Key]
        public int ProductImageId { get; set; }

        public int ProductID { get; set; }


        public string ProductImageTitle { get; set; }
        public string ProductImageUploadUrl { get; set; }
        public string ProductImageRealPath { get; set; }

        public string ServerIpAddress { get; set; }
        public string ProductImageAltTag { get; set; }

        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

        public string Image { set; get; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well you're not passing a model with `IEnumerable<solitude.models.ProductImages>` to your partial.. Add them here: `@Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicturesList.cshtml", (model to send to partial view))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial view is strongly typed to a collection of `ProductImages`. But in your main view when you are calling this partial view, you are not passing the model (which is the collection of ProductImage objects) to this partial view. If you are not explcitily passing the model, it will try to use the model for the parent view. In your case your parent view is strongly `ProductImageVm` view model class. So it is not maching with what the partial view is expecting.

The solution is to pass a valid collection of ProductImages. If your view model has a collection property of that type you can do that

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicturesList.cshtml",Model.Images)
```

Assuming `Images` of type `IEnumerable<solitude.models.ProductImages>`

Ideally it is not a great idea to mix entity classes with view models. So i would create a view model class for the ProductImage partial view and use that as the property

```
public class ProductImg
{
  public string Title { set;get;}
  public string FileName  { set;get;}
  // or path as needed
}
public class EditProductImageVm
{
   public string Title { set;get;} //for the new item
   public IFormFile Image { set;get; }  //for the new item

   public IEnumerable<ProductImg> Images { set;get;}
}
```

Now make sure main view is not strongly typed to EditProductImageVm and your partial view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<ProductImg>`. Also you need to await the call to `PartialAsync` method

```
@model YourNameSpaceGoesHere.EditProductImageVm 
<div>
   @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicturesList.cshtml",Model.Images);
</div>
<form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="FileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                 method="post" >
    <input asp-for="Title" />
    <input asp-for="Image" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And your partial view will be

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNameSpaceGoesHere.ProductImg>
<h3>Images</h3>
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
             <td>
                <!-- adjust the below img src path as needed -->
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/uploads/"+item.FileName)"/>
             </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I am showing you what my product images is again in the above edit many thanks  this is a entity so please advice me how I should do this

Comment: Thank you is there any good progress bars built into mvc or is that still a sep thing

Comment: There might be some client side libraries to do that. Just google and you will find a ton

Comment: you have helped me yet again thanks question how would one pass the product id to this to allow filtering as partial views cant have controllers or can then ? I want to filter the list where productid =